# Does bytecode have to be converted to machine code?

Tags: java, jvm

I am confused that for in the role of the JVM. Is my understanding correct that JVM only converts the Bytecode to Machine code? So essentially there is communcation between the OS, JVM and CPU. My assumption is that the bytecode gets converted to Machine code and then processed by CPU.

Comment: i suggest you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JVM` is a virtual machine.

Its like when you install some OS(Linux, Solaris) on VMware or VirtualBox, those are virtual machines. They run on top of the host OS.

`JVM` is different in a way that it's machine code is `bytecode`. There are machines which have high level languages as their machine code. If JVM were to run on the hardware and not on the host OS then it would expect a hardware capable of using `bytecode` instruction set.

However since it's runs on top of host OS, any bytecode instruction is communicated to the host after being converted to machine code. In case of VMware/VirtualBox, these softwares take care of it. In case of JVM it's done by `JRE`.

Comment: So every bytecode instruction is converted to machine code? and then communicated to the OS, and OS to cpu?

Comment: Yup, but JVM doesn't participate in that, it has to be done by the wrapper environment, in this case JRE. Think of it as running a batch file or shell script, every instruction in the batch file is an instruction equivalent to the instructions in bytecode. However interpreter will have to find appropriate program to run according to each instruction in the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA is a compiled and interpreted language and not only just the interpreted language. Lets see step by step execution of its program.

1. Suppose we write a java program and save it as “hello.java” in a folder somewhere on a hard disk.
2. The name of the java compiler is “javac”. For its compilation we have to write “javac hello.java” on the command line.
3. At this stage the high level code gets converted to the machine level code. Java converts it into a .class file as “hello.class” . This code is also known as a byte code because every instruction in this file is of 1 Byte.
4. This byte code can also be taken away on any other platform like
   Mac, Linux or Windows. It only takes a JVM of respective OS for its
   execution. Hence, JAVA is known as a first platform independent and
   architecturally neutral language.
5. Now, for its execution, interpreter is used. It is named as a “java” itself. For its interpretation, “java hello.java” should be used on the command line. It internally invokes class loader which is responsible for loading the ‘hello.class’ file from hard disk to JVM’s address space.
6. Here there comes a ‘Byte code verifier’ which verifies the code to avoid run time failures. After successful verification, JVM executes the byte by byte code with the help of OS.

Thus the whole java program gets executed by JVM and OS. While JVM acts as a mini OS for the java program and it concerns OS only when the instructions are not in its scope.